# Use javascript to compress images to limit filesize and resize to limit dimension before upload to server

Tags: javascript, image

How to use JavaScript compress images to limit file size and resize to limit dimension before upload to server.

Comment: Draw it on the `canvas` first, you can resize it by this step, then use [canvas.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to get the `src` and set it on image, you can notice that it accepts 2nd parameter which is related to quality.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5 you can resize images client-side using the canvas element. You can also take the new data and send it to a server. See [this tutorial](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/)